# How to do reset the google earth plugin with javascript?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

Sometimes the ge plugin wont load kml via the fetchKml function. When this happens I have to kill the ge plugin processes and then it works fine.

Is there a way to do this within the browser? A setTimeout will catch when it's not loading and I'd like to reset the plugin so it will work.

I would want something like google.earth.reset();

Thanks

Comment: could that be a problem with the cache of the browser? Possibly if the KML is already in the cache of the browser it won't be fecthed correctly again. Have you considered this fact?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reset function, but there is an undocumented kill method for the GEPlugin object.

```
// where ge is a reference to the plugin.
ge.kill_();
```

That said there is probably a reason why the kml does not appear to be loading, as nuxy says, if you post and example of the actual code you are using then it would be easier to offer help.

**EDIT:**

Also rather than using an undocumented method you could just re-load the database which will reset the plugin. Something like the following set up should work well.

```
var ge = null;
google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback);

var initCallback = function(object) {
  ge = object;
  ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
}

var failureCallback = function(error) {
  alert(error):
}

var reset = function() {
  document.getElementById('map3d').innerHTML = '';
  google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback);
}
```

To use simply call the reset method.

reset();

Comment: Recent plugin versions (tested on Earth v7.1.2.2041 / API v1.010) don't have a `pluginInstance.Kill_()` method, but do have `.kill_()` which behaves as described.

Comment: Just a typo - it was always lowercase.